# Failed to run Zeppelin notebook demo Spark Streaming - Hortonworks sandbox

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-zeppelin

I tried to run the note book demo available on Zeppelin in Hortonworks sandbox 2.4 (Notebook named twitter) to learn SparkStreaming. According the instruction on the top of notebook (/* BEFORE START....), I logged on Ambari to modify the configuration of Yarn service.

- CPU => Container: Minimum Container Size (VCores) 4; Maximum Container Size (Vcores): 8
- Memory
- Node: 2250MB
- Container: Minimum Container Size: 768MB; Maximum Container Size: 2250MB

All services are restarted after modifying but when I came back to Zeppelin to run the notebook, the second paragraph (/* UPDATE YOUR TWITTER CREDENTIALS */....) was always on the state "running" but never "finished". All twitter credentials are already updated.

P/S: without modifying the YARN configuration, I could run the second paragraph, but when running the 3rd, It was always "running" but never "finished"

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

if the error is
`Error:YarnApplicationState: ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register`

change the value of `yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage` to 99 and the value of `yarn maximum-am-resource-percent` to 100